# How to remove empty strings/null with mapping on scala?

Tags: scala, filter, null

```
val labResult = RDDlab.map(p => LabResult(p(1).toString, dateFormat.parse(p(8).toString), p(7).toString, p(14).toString.toDouble))
```

I need to only map those rows for which p(14) is not null. How do I do this on scala?

Answer (score 0):

```
val labResult = RDDlab.filter(p => p(14).toString != null && !p(14).toString.isEmpty).map(p => LabResult(p(1).toString, dateFormat.parse(p(8).toString), p(7).toString, p(14).toString.toDouble))
```

user `filter` to do that.

Comment: I am now getting two errors: Type mismatch, expected: Column, actual: (nothing) => Boolean and Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: (nothing) => Boolean

Comment: @javabeginner with `toString`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use StringUtils here to filter out null and empty strings.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
val labResult = RDDlab.filter(p => StringUtils.isNotEmpty(p(14).toString)).map(p => LabResult(p(1).toString, dateFormat.parse(p(8).toString), p(7).toString, p(14).toString.toDouble))
```

Answer (score 0):

For this Scala provides the `collect` method which can be neatly combined with `pattern matching` and `pattern guards`.

```
val labResult = 
  RDDlab
    .collect{
       case p if p(14) != null && p(14).toString.isDefined =>
         LabResult(
           p(1).toString,
           dateFormat.parse(p(8).toString),
           p(7).toString,
           p(14).toStr
         )
     }
```